# Non zero solution of homogenous system equations

Tags: determinant

If the system of linear equations $$x+2ay+az=0$$ $$x+3by+bz=0$$ $$x+4cy+cz=0$$ has a non-zero solution, then find a relation between $a, b, c$ .

My attempt

I tried to find the discriminant to be zero assuming this to be a non trivial solution but it came out wrong.

Comment: What does “discriminant” mean in this context?

Comment: I think determinant does she/he meant

Comment: It's determinant. Btw I can't edit the question

Comment: Only if the determinant of the homogeneous system is equal zero, we will find other solutions than the zero vector.

Comment: I have found the following relation between $a,b,c$ : $bc-2ac+ab=0$ .

Comment: I have found the same but it doesn't match the options. Maybe the solution is wrong

Comment: @GENESECT What are the given options?

Comment: AP, GP, HP and a+b+2c=0

Comment: The determinant is just $a(2c-b)-bc$.  From here it's the condition that @Matko found: $ab+bc=2ac$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Eliminating $x$ we get
$$y(3b-2a)+z(b-a)=0$$
$$y(4c-2a)+z(c-a)=0$$
Now you have distinguish several cases.

Comment: By distinguishing several cases, what do you mean

Comment: I mean $$b-a\neq 0$$ or $$b-a=0$$ etc

Answer (score 0):

As the determinant is $ab+bc-2ac$ we have a non-trivial kernel iff $b(a+c)=2ac$.  Now if $a=-c$ it follows that $a=c=0$ and $b$ may be any real number.  Otherwise $b=\frac{2ac}{a+c}$.